# Get json via laravel command - Failed to open stream

Tags: php, json, laravel-5

I am writing a laravel command to read in reddit comments. I am running `Laravel Framework version 5.2.45`. My handle method looks like the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

class reddit extends Command
{
    /**...**/
    /**
     * Execute the console command.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        $str = json_decode(file_get_contents('www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json'));
        foreach ($str as $comments) {
            // dd($comments);
            foreach ($comments->data->children as $comment) {
                if ($comment->body_html == 'You') {
                    print_r($comment);
                } else {
                    print_r($comment);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When executing the command I get the following error message:

> [ErrorException]
>   file_get_contents(www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

**UPDATE**
Using the following URL `reddit.com/r/all/comments.json` I get:

> ```
>  [ErrorException]                                                                                     
>   file_get_contents(reddit.com/r/all/comments.json): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
> ```
>
> Exception trace:
>        () at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/Console/Commands/reddit.php:55
>        Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError() at n/a:n/a
>        file_get_contents() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/Console/Commands/reddit.php:55
>        App\Console\Commands\reddit->handle() at n/a:n/a
>        call_user_func_array() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:507
>        Illuminate\Container\Container->call() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:169
>        Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:256
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:155
>        Illuminate\Console\Command->run() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:794
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:186
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:117
>        Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:107
>        Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() at /home/ubuntu/workspace/artisan:36

Comment: What happens when you've replace the url to [https://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json] (with https:// as a prefix)

Comment: @eeya Thx for your reply! Please see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, worked for me: There is `307 Internal Redirect` on `http://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json`

[image]

**Try this:**

```
  print_r(file_get_contents("https://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json"));
```

Comment: Any suggestions for a potential reason why `http` or `no-http` does not work?

Comment: If is not working because when you hit this url `http://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json` it redirects it to `https://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json`, so that why it is saying not content found for `http://www.reddit.com/r/all/comments.json`